How do Calvinists reconcile Christ's election of Judas Iscariot to be a disciple only to be betrayed by him?
Britannica article on Calvinism states

Calvin had certain approximate and attainable tests. He did not
require the experience of the new birth, which is so inward and
intangible, though to be sure later Calvinism moved away from him on
this point and agonized over the signs of election. For Calvin there
were three tests: the profession of faith; a rigorously disciplined
Christian deportment; and a love of the sacraments, which meant the
Lord’s Supper, since infant baptism was not to be repeated. Persons
who could meet these three tests could assume their election and stop
worrying

If Christ chose Judas to be a disciple, and if Christ is part of the Trinitarian Godhead being all-knowing and omnipotent...
According to Calvinism, how is it that Christ elected Judas Iscariot to discipleship, one of Christ's inner circle, only to be betrayed by him?
Calvinists would say Jesus predetermined Judas election to the discipleship because the Bible records he chose him.
Because God chose Judas, is not a disciple predetermined to be saved? What happened in this example?

How does the quotation relate to the rest of the question?


The Brittanica article in no way gives a faithful summary of John Calvin's doctrine. 2. Just reading Jesus' own words regarding Judas fully explains his purpose in choosing Judas. There is nothing to 'reconcile'.


Perhaps you should phrase your comment as a proper answer Nigel? There is plenty to reconcile if you accept the fundamental concept of Calvinism which is "God picked ahead of time who was saved and who wasn't, because He is all powerful and all knowing"

@Nigel...one of the tests according to Calvin was the sacraments. Judas attended the last supper and Christ washed his feet and gave him food. That means even after cleansing and eating the body of Christ, Judas betrayed Him

@adam Calvin was well aware of false teachers and heretics in the church, and no doubt he knew that they could outwardly observe everything while being frauds. "Judas ate the last supper, so he must have been elect" is a gross misrepresentation of Calvin's views, it doesn't even fit the article you cited which calls for love of the sacraments (presumably unfeigned). We have no reason to assume Judas loved the sacraments, and in any case this is only one of three tests referenced. His thieving and betrayal would clearly fail the second.

Our Lord chose Judas Iscariot to be a disciple: but this choosing was outward. Our Lord did not choose him to be a true believer inwardly.   He never repented of his sin nor believed on Christ from his heart.  He looked after the money bag, the common purse of the whole group, and regularly helped himself, John 12:4-6.
His unbelief was so great he betrayed our Lord, not only after seeing so many miracles performed by Christ, but also after seeing so many miracles performed by the other disciples and performed by himself also.  There is every reason to believe he himself performed miracles in the name of Jesus Christ.. how else was it the disciples did not know who the betrayer would be?
He had the faith that can do miracles, but not the faith that saves. Even when he was sorry for his betrayal all he could say was "I have betrayed innocent blood".  He did not say "I have betrayed the Lord of glory".. he couldn't, because he still did not believe it.
Judas Iscariot was chosen by our Lord to follow him as a disciple and to be his betrayer. "Jesus knew from the beginning .. who should betray him", John 6:64.
In the same place our Lord said "No man can come to me unless it were given to him by my Father".  Judas never came to Jesus spiritually, he was never chosen to be a true believer.
Judas loved money not the Lord.  You cannot serve two masters, Matthew 6:24; "the love of money is the root of all evil", 1st Timothy 6:10. Only one can be your true master, and Judas's true master was Mammon. He loved money and despised the Lord.  He was the forerunner of those multitudes today who profess faith in Christ but are greedy for gain. He had no compassion for the poor, psalm 41:1, and so it came to pass what was predicted of him in the Psalm:

my own familiar friend, in whom I trusted, which did eat my bread, has lifted his heel against me, Psalm 41:9.

He is also prophecied in the whole of Psalm 109, especially verse 8:

Let his days be few, and let another take his office [of apostle]. See Acts 1:20.

These prophecies concerning Judas were given so that the other Apostles might not be riddled with  self-doubt, thinking, "if Judas could betray the Lord, then so could any of us too"!  No, Judas betrayal was foreordained in the Old Testament, he was never truly chosen by the Father to come to Jesus spiritually, John 6:65.

Have I not chosen you, and one of you is a devil?", John 6:69.

Daily faith and repentance mark the believer, not position, whether it be a Church member, a deacon, an elder, a Pastor, priest or vicar, or even an Apostle.
If anyone loves money they follow Judas Iscariot, it would be better if they had never been born.
But those who love the Lord, the elect, let us make our calling and election sure, 2 Peter 1:10, taking warning that neither outward position nor reputation is any substitute for daily repentance and confidence in the finished work of our Saviour, and in the cleansing power of the blood and the Holy Spirit, trusting that

"if we confess our sins he is faithful and just to forgive us our sins and cleanse us from all unrighteousness", 1 John 1:9.


This is certainly more elegant then my answer. I will keep my personal opinion about predestination out of the comment section.

That saves me from answering! Just to add that Jesus spent a night in prayer before choosing the 12, seeking the Father's will as to who to choose. So the Father must have made it known to Jesus that the betrayer must be included, from the start, and undoubtedly the O.T. prophecies on that were already known to Christ. Judas was called to follow; but he did not follow - he betrayed. Also, is it right to say the Bible indicates Judas partook of the various Passover cups, but not the cup in the new covenant? Some suppose he must have but, no; he need not. Anything particular on that? +1

@Anne - Two great points!  The Gospel passage which is clearest  about the Lord's Supper is Luke 22:19-23 where it is clear Judas partook of at least the bread.  It is still possible he did not drink of the cup.  But whether he did or did not there is still an application for us:  partaking of the Lord's Supper is no proof you are saved; salvation is all a matter of faith and repentance; we must not put our trust in anything else. As for our Lord praying all night before he chose the twelve, yes how often have we heard his prayer may have been lengthened by thoughts of his final week/betrayal.

I'll attempt to answer this in the form that you requested without going to much into my own views. I will say however that in the past before I converted to Orthodoxy I was Presbyterian. So I think I can speak a little bit on the subject without being just an internet guy. :)

Calvinism has this main fundamental aspect: Predestination and it interacts with the concept of "Eternal security"

This is what causes all the headaches such as "If Judas was supposed to betray Jesus so that salvation could occur, Jesus chose Judas specifically, the 12 were promised thrones in heaven, and if Judas did his part for the salvation of all: Shouldn't that mean that Judas is saved?
Now that the question is defined and the Calvinism issue as well here is how Calvinism attempts to resolve this matter: We look at John 6:37 and...

In order for John 6:37 to be consistently applied to the believer, it is not merely the Father giving believers to Christ, it is also them COMING TO HIM. Judas never came to the Lord, he always referred to Christ as "master" and not Lord, and actively sought to betray him. This is seen even in the Lord's supper where the other 11 call Jesus LORD and Judas calls him Rabbi instead of LORD.  (Source some baptist blog discussing Calvinism as heresy)

So I think the way Calvinism manages to handle Judas is that he "never came to Christ", even if he was chosen he did not get that "irresistible urge of grace" that they use to explain actions from our perspective.

This does not address the FACT that Christ elected him to be among the 12. If christ is God and elected a betrayer, then Predestination states that Christ elected a betrayer to his inner group of DISCIPLES. Judas was a disciple. Christ could have simply turned Judas away, but he didn't. That suggests Judas fate was not predetermined.

Adam, with all due respect. The debate about if Calvinism is heresy is NOT the issue. The question asked for how a Calvinist would resolve the issue of Judas, and I believe I presented that.

And that is the last "blockquote" in my answer. I had to search for awhile to find that explanation. The majority of information on this matter is presenting calvinism as heresy. But you didn't ask for why calvinism is heresy, you asked how would a calvinist explain Judas. I answered. If you want to have a conversation where we both bash on calvinism we can create a chat room and pound on how wildly flawed the logic is and how many Bible verses they have to ignore.

@Wyrsa, the quotes are lacking citations.
